# require 'tire' gem not being mentioned in a model class but usage of it still works in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, tire

Im reviewing code of a rails application I inherited and I'm no expert in rails. In the gemfile for the application there is: `gem 'tire'`. Great, but I expect to use require 'tire' in models or controllers to be able to use the libraries this gem provides. 
According to the documentation of a particular gem it says it needs to be included as a mixin in a model class.

```
 include Tire::Model::Search
 include Tire::Model::Callbacks
```

Or the documentation mentions to use `require 'tire'` to the model class where you plan to use the tire gem.
But in the project I don't see any of these require/includes in the models. The models are just using the api without requiring/including like so:

```
ret = Tire.index "icrd" do 
            import [icrdObj]

            refresh
        end
```

How does this work? Where should I look in the rails project to get an understanding of why require or include is not needed? Is there some kind of autoloading going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler has a lot of nice methods. `Bundler.setup` ensures you can require gems easily in your app.

`Bundler.require(:default, :production)` for example (it accepts group names) requires **all gems** in the gemfile automatically by performing `require 'tire'`, `require 'rails'` and such, for you.

You can skip auto-require for some gems by adding `require: false` near your gem row in gemfile, like

`gem 'rails', require: false`

Check [Bundler.require](http://bundler.io/groups.html) documentation (which is placed under `groups`)

Comment: Wait a min, are you telling me, when I add the gem to the gemfile of a rails project, and run bundle install, it automatically adds all the gems to the rails project for me to use anywhere? So this way, I can use the gem's API anywhere in the entire rails project without worrying about adding `include 'tire'` to the top of the ruby file in which I want to use the gem?

Comment: You don't have to worry about `require 'tire'`, you **need** however to use `include Tire::Model::Search` if the gem requires you to do so, only `require` is not needed with bundler in rails

Comment: why I don't understand is `require` not needed if we use bundler. But why would Tire::Model::Search need to be `included`?

Comment: Those are two completely independent steps! First, it's not Bundler in general that does this, it's specifically `Bundler.require` which **is not used everywhere**, Rails does it, but not a lot of other gems that I'm aware of. Second, and you need to study Ruby to fix this missing knowledge, `require` it's like a low-level "copy-paste the source code here if it hasn't been done already. `include`, instead, it's a completely different thing, you don't `include` a file, you can only `include` Ruby modules (defined as `module Something`). And that's specific **per class**

Comment: Not to mention, you can have 1, 2, 3 (or more) classes in one file and you might want to `include Tire::Model::Search` in one of them but not in all 3, so it can't be done automatically. If you know something about [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), `including` that everywhere will add methods to **all classes**, which instantly kills the [Single Responsability Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). `include` is a high level Object oriented functionality, not just a "low-level" `require`.

Comment: Excellent, when you explained it to me like that (OOP way) it made sense since I'm a java guy. So as I understand, `include` is basically a composition relationship, you include behavior of other objects into other classes so they can also respond to those included messages.

Comment: But that brings up a question: `require` is like importing the entire ruby file into another. Rails takes care of figuring out the actual name of the file that `include` is referencing. But what is include referencing exactly then if it's not the name of the file? Is that name defined anywhere? Let's say, `include 'tire'` is actually referencing a file called `tire_gem.rb`. Where is this mapping of `tire_gem.rb` and `tire`

Comment: Rails follows some conventions to find out the file when `including` a module, but when relates to gems, it doesn't deal with that at all. First, you **can't** `include 'tire'`, you can include a module, not a file. A module is more or less a Java interface **with** defined method implementations, and `include` is more or less Java `implements`. Rails find out that you use `gem 'tire'` and so it does the only thing it knows: `require 'tire'` (it "requires" the gem name), which in turn require [these files](https://github.com/seejohnrun/tire/blob/master/lib/tire.rb).

Comment: Notice that this it's a Ruby convention, there should be a file named in the same way the gem is named in gem root (`lib/gemname.rb`), Rails knows the gem name through the Gemfile, and tries to `require` a file using that gem name. Bundle takes care to find out that file in that gem and require it. From there, control is given to the gem, which in turns require the files it wants. One of those includes module [Search](https://github.com/seejohnrun/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/model/search.rb) so at that point you can finally type `include Tire::Model::Search` wherever you want

Comment: Everything you said in the last post made sense to me up to the point where you mention Bundle takes care to find out that file in that gem and require it. When I type bundle install, what does that do? Does it require all the gems in each ruby class? I though that was the responsibility of the rails framework

Comment: Bundle install just takes care of installing the gem on your system, then Bundler exposes two methods (which are indeed used in rails): `Bundler.setup` and `Bundler.require`. They are both called by rails, bundler just exposes them but the "feature" of requiring gems from the gem file, comes from bundler, even if it's Rails calling them (Rails is the one who triggers the **requires**). Bundler.setup basically ensures your ruby `$LOAD_PATH` include paths like `/home/youruser/.rvm/gems/tire/`, `Bundler.require` calls `require 'tire'`, same thing replicated for all gems in your gemfile

Answer (score 1):

When a gem is included in a `Gemfile`, the associated `require ..` statement is automatically called.

See http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/10/13/how-does-rails-handle-gems/ for an explanation of how rails handles gems.

From that blogpost:

> So, Bundler will look in your Gemfile for gems belonging to each of
>   those groups, and call require on each of the gems it finds. If you
>   have a gem nokogiri, it’ll call require "nokogiri" for you. And that’s
>   why your gems usually just work in Rails, without any extra code on
>   your part.

Comment: Thanks. What about `include Tire::Model::Search` and  `include Tire::Model::Callbacks` ? Is that needed and why?

Comment: Not to be rude, but you really need to study Ruby before Rails if you make this question, it will make everything looks clear.

Comment: @HorseVoice: The `include` statements in this case provides you a clean way of implementing `search` functionality to a model, as explained in https://github.com/karmi/retire#activemodel-integration. You can use the api directly as well (which seems to be the case in the app you inherited).

Comment: So in a nutshell from what I understand, Bundler basically does an automatic include of all gems in the rails gemfile. Is that right? So this way, I can use the gem's API anywhere in the entire rails project without worrying about adding `include 'tire'` to the top of the ruby file in which I want to use the gem?